# android File.exists fails to check a file on SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, file-exists

`if(new File("/mnt/sdcard/t.m").exists()) {...}`

When I create a java program using Eclipse and debug it on my Android phone, it tests right.
But when I put it into a app in my Android system, it does not detect the file.

And, in another app (built in my Android system, too), though I've put following in AndroidManifest.xml,

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

the code below causes an exception saying no permission,

`File f=new File("/mnt/sdcard/a.t"); f.createNewFile();`

Thank you. I'm new to Android.

Answer (score 1):

in [Permission to write to the SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121833/permission-to-write-to-the-sd-card):

> You're right that the SD Card
>   directory is /sdcard but you shouldn't
>   be hard coding it. Instead, make a
>   call to
>   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
>   to get the directory:
>
> File sdDir =
>   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
>   If you haven't done so already, you
>   will need to give you app the correct
>   permission to write to the SD Card by
>   adding this to your Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
  />
```

Just change it to read (instead of write)

Comment: I had tried all your code. Not working. the file can be listed out by adb shell,so hard coding cannot make it wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was in a hurry and didn't read properly! Go here and check the state of the storage: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) and I had checked this. The small testing program works verified it. The problem is the difference between my larger program by "make" and the smaller program by Eclipse.