# Folder creation in android phone

Tags: android

How to create a folder in android phone and move sms in it

Answer (score 1):

if you want to save data on the internal space, look at this [resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

if you want to do that on the sdcard, you can access the external media by using the external storage api. [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) will help you. note that your application needs to have the [permission to write to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121833/permission-to-write-to-the-sd-card). you have to set that to your manifest file.

concerning the sms accessing, there is already a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android) for that.

please use the search before you post a question, there are already some questions about the topic you asked.