# how to create xml file in android

Tags: android

Guys i have a problem that my code gives an Exception as Permission Denied when we write a xml in android. can any one tell that How it will be removed.

```
package com.ex.createXml;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class createXml extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File newxmlfile = new File("/data/new.xml");
        try{
            newxmlfile.createNewFile();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("IOException", "Exception in create new File(");
        }
        FileOutputStream fileos = null;
        try{
            fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("FileNotFoundException",e.toString());
        }
        XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        try{
        serializer.setOutput(fileos, "UTF-8");
        serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
        serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
        serializer.startTag(null, "root");
        serializer.startTag(null, "Child1");
        serializer.endTag(null, "Child1");
        serializer.startTag(null, "Child2");
        serializer.attribute(null, "attribute", "value");
        serializer.endTag(null, "Child2");
        serializer.startTag(null, "Child3");
        serializer.text("Some text inside child 3");
        serializer.endTag(null,"Child3");
        serializer.endTag(null,"root");
        serializer.endDocument();
        serializer.flush();
        fileos.close();
        //TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception","Exception occured in wroting");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> File newxmlfile = new File("C:/new.xml");
> ```

You're trying to create your file on drive C. Android is a linux-based system, so there are no drives there. The storage devices can be mounted to root ("/") or any other folder.

For your application `/data/<pakcage-name>` folder is available. Try to write there. Also, you can try to write to external storage, but your progrma will need a permission to do that:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This should be mentioned within your manifest file.

Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: thanks Vladimir, and you are true that it gives a Permission denied Exception. so, can u tell how it can be remove.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your trying to create a file at the location of c:/ which is not a valid path identifier on a android system. Android comes from a linux environment.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html follow this link to learn more about data storage on android

If you want to create a file on your local pc you first need to create it on your Android device and then pull it from the device (either the emulator or your real phone)

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to write to that location.

```
File newxmlfile = new File("/data/new.xml");
```

You could save it to the [internal storage, or cache.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the Android security model you can't write to `/data/new.xml`. That's trying to right to the root file system which is why you are getting permission denied. Try it without the leading slash.

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("new.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(...);
```

That should put it relative to your app.

Comment: but where it stores the file?

Comment: @SanatPandey Hey where does this store the file? did you find the answer? I dont know where the file is created??

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the necessary permission for this?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

[Permission to write to the SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121833/permission-to-write-to-the-sd-card)

Comment: I have already set the manifest permissions but error remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
File xmlDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/data/new.xml");
```