# Reading File in different activities

Tags: android, file-io

I am writing results from one activity to a file in my android emulator but, i am not able to read the same file in other activities.Actually i want to display the contents of the file in another activity in the edittext box.What I have to do to write the file to memory card and read the same in any other activity ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special, sd-card files are world readable.  It's always better to post code and stating what's not working.
Hint: you might also want to look at Intent.putExtra(...) functions for sharing data between activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android also has some built-in functionality for storing data between activities. For example, you can create a SharedPreferences object and store this output as a String, with key value output (SharedPreferences uses a Map, where object is a simple type, such as String, int, boolean, etc. Using mode_world_writeable to define how you share between activities will let you retrieve this sharedPreferences mapping amongst any activities in your package.

`String fileOutput //output from the activity to share as String.`

`SharedPreferences user_settings;`

`SharedPreferences.Editor user_settings_editor;`

`user_settings = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.user_prefs_file), Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);`

`user_settings_editor = user_settings.edit();`

`user_settings_editor.putString("output", fileOutput);`

`user_settings_editor.commit();`

Answer (score 2):

Check out the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder).  You won't have any problem reading something that was written in another Activity.  Make sure you have the correct permissions as shown in [Permission to write to the SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121833/permission-to-write-to-the-sd-card).