# Accessing application Databases on my Android device(LG Optimus one p500)

Tags: android, database, adb

I have created an android application for my Android device which stores records into sqlite databases and even the retrieval of the data from the database works correctly on my application. Now i want to access the database file located in the location as follows:

/data/data/org.project.compdroid.dash1/databases/data

where data is my database file.
This data file i want to export to my pc to keep a backup of all the records. 
for this I first tried accessing it from the emulator by the command

adb pull /data/data/org.project.compdroid.dash1/databases/data [local address path]

this worked correctly for the emulator. but when i try to copy the same file from my Android phone it says permission denied. I think since I am not the root user for my phone I am not allowed to access it and I am allowed to achieve it in my emulator since I am already rooted there.
Now is there a way by which i will be able to copy the data file from my android phone without rooting it? or is rooting the only solution for my problem?

Please do suggest any other technique(if there are any) for copying the database files from an android phone to my computer.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can include code in your app that will copy the file from internal storage onto the sd card, since your App has full access to its own storage. See [How to backup database to SD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995320/how-to-backup-database-file-to-sdcard-on-android) and [Backing up your Android..](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7749)

You could also spit out the Db as a text file which can then be imported into any DB.

Comment: When i tried to follow the tutorial in the link you had mentioned, i get the following errors in the logcat output:

Comment: 07-24 21:21:15.484: ERROR/Status:(4221): Permission denied
07-24 21:21:15.484: ERROR/Status:(4221): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
07-24 21:21:15.484: ERROR/Status:(4221):     at java.io.File.createNewFileImpl(Native Method)
07-24 21:21:15.484: ERROR/Status:(4221):     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1160)

Comment: is this because i am using an un-rooted phone?

Comment: I know this is old, but it looks like you didn't give the app SD card read/write permission. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121833/permission-to-write-to-the-sd-card