# Check if file exists on SD card on Android

Tags: android

I want to check if a text file exists on the SD card. The file name is mytextfile.txt. Below is the code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("sdcard/mytextfile.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

How can I check whether this file exists?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This should do the trick, I've replaced the hard coded SDcard reference to the recommended API call [getExternalCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29):

```
File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "mytextfile.txt" );
if (file.exists()) {
  //Do action
}
```

Comment: please note: getExternalCacheDir() may not be what you want. If you are wanting a directory on sd that will be cleared up after app is uninstalled (e.g. a 'cache' dir), use getExternalCacheDir(). But if you want the top level dir of the sd card, then you may be better using: File sdDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());

Answer (score 2):

See this file System in android :  [Working with SDCard’s filesystem in Android](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2010/01/13/working-with-sdcards-filesystem-in-android/)

you just check

```
if(file.exists()){
//
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using this you can check the file is present or not in sdcard **

```
File file = new File(sdcardpath+ "/" + filename);
if (file.exists())
 {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a file, and set it to be the required file, and check if it exists.

```
String FILENAME="mytextfile.txt";
File fileToCheck = new File(getExternalCacheDirectory(), FILENAME);
if (fileToCheck.exists()) {
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(&quot;sdcard/mytextfile.txt&quot;, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
}
```

Have Fun!

Comment: It's best not to use the hard coded reference to the SD card, see my earlier answer for a better way to access the external storage.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileOutputStream` constructor will throw a `FileNotFound` exception if the specified file doesn't exist. See the [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29) for more information.

Also, make sure you have permission to [access the SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121833/permission-to-write-to-the-sd-card).

Answer (score 0):

check IF condition with Boolean type like

```
File file = new File(path+filename);
if (file.exists() == true)
{
//Do something
}
```

Comment: `== true` in the code above is redondant. You could use `if (file.exists())` instead.