# How to check if a file exists in a directory in sd card

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

I want to check whether a given file exists in android sd card. I am trying it out with creating a file using the absolute path and checking with `file.exists()` but its not working. The URL for the file is  `"file:///mnt/sdcard/book1/page2.html"` and the file does exist. But somehow `file.exists()` isn't showing the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if file exists on SD card on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697650/check-if-file-exists-on-sd-card-on-android)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/book1/page2.html");

if(myFile.exists()){
    ...
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 7):

Try like this:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/book1/page2.html");
if (file.exists()) {
    /*...*/
}
```

Also make sure you have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

You can check as follows:

```
  File file = new File(getExternalCacheDirectory(), "mytextfile.txt" );
  if (file.exists()) {
      //Do action
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File logFile = new File(
        android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/book1/", "page2.tml");
if (logFile.exists())
    System.out.println("file exists");
else
    System.out.println("file does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "your/file/path");

if(yourFile.exists())
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String filepath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(); 
String FileName = "Yourfilename" ;
File FileMain = new File(filepath, FileName); 
if (FileMain.exists()){ 
do somthing here                     
}else{}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(path+filename);
if (file.exists())
{
//Do something
}
```

checked, this will work