# how to check file exist on sd card or not

Tags: android, image, sqlite

i have a activity where i have a image view..i capture image and image get stored in sd card folder. at the time of capterd image a folder will create in sd card and the respective clicked image stored in sd card card folder. And absolute path of that image inserted in sqlite database. i get the table index of image and split the path to get  `file/image name`..,,i want to know how to check that image name exist in `sd` card folder or not at the time of post image to server..

```
String trp=AppDBManager.w1;  ///image name get in Aapdbmanager class variable w1   
       File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Retailsolution/"+trp+"");

        if(dir.exists()){

            //code 
}
```

Comment: Your code is right, whats the problem?

Comment: i am not getting the image on server..

Comment: when i manually put the name of image in  file then got the image on server

 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Retailsolution/x-pankaj_Facade_2016-04-05_05-30-29.jpg");

Comment: i want to get image from database without knowing what image name is exactly stored in database .i only get the index and check the file name is exist on sd card or not..if exist then post that to server..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if file exists on SD card on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697650/check-if-file-exists-on-sd-card-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), mFolder);
if (root.exists()) {

    File mFile;
    mFile = new File(root, mFileNameOut);
    if (mFile.exists()) {
        //YOUR CODE
    }
}
```

Comment: what is  mfileNameOut ?.

Comment: Your file name in your torage

Comment: i store the image name in string can i use it ?

Comment: You should use the name of the file that you want to now if exist... Yes, you can use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(path);

if(!file.exists()){
    //your code if file not exists
}else {  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "mytextfile.txt" );
if (file.exists()) {
  //Do action
}
```