# Why is it that i am still not able to create a new directory in sdcard after capturing an image for my app?

Tags: java, android, image, directory, android-sdcard

```
public class EditUploads extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView ivEditUploads, imgSave;
    EditText etxtPrice, etxtDescription;
    Spinner sCategories;

    PhotoDbAdapter ourHelper;
    Long pRowId = null;

    private String description, category, price, imagepath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_uploads);

        findViewById();

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent()
                    .getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent()
                    .getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
            ivEditUploads.setImageBitmap(b);

        }

        addItemsOnSCategories();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

        String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Myfolder/"
                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    }

    private void findViewById() {
        ivEditUploads = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivEditUploads);
        imgSave = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSave);
        sCategories = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sCategories);
        etxtDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtDescription);
        etxtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtPrice);

        imgSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void addItemsOnSCategories() {

        sCategories = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sCategories);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("His");
        list.add("Hers");
        list.add("Kid's");
        list.add("Everything Else");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sCategories.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        sCategories
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Bitmap sourceBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ivEditUploads.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/Neatpicks");
        myDir.mkdirs();

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fname);
        Uri mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null,
                null);
        int column_index_data = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "Neatpicks");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("Neatpicks", "failed to create directory");
                return;
            }
        }

        description = etxtDescription.getText().toString();
        category = sCategories.getOnItemSelectedListener().toString();
        price = etxtPrice.getText().toString();
        imagepath = capturedImageFilePath;

        PhotoDbAdapter saveUploads = new PhotoDbAdapter(EditUploads.this);
        saveUploads.open();

        if (pRowId == null) {

            long saveUpId = saveUploads.createEntry(description, category,
                    price, imagepath);
            saveUploads.close();

            if (saveUpId > 0) {
                pRowId = saveUpId;

                Intent uploads = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Mobile.class);

                startActivity(uploads);

            }

        }
    }

}
```

i had tried to use the mkdir methods however, i was still not able to see the images in a newly created folder...i am hoping someone would help point out my mistakes and guide me along cause i am fairly new to android programming. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you see any kind errors in Logcat??

Comment: did you add the correct permissions in manifest file?

Comment: nope. it can be run smoothly however nothing is being displayed in the gridview of my another activity

Comment: @nitesh goel  is this the correct one?                                  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

Your app probably needs to request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121833/permission-to-write-to-the-sd-card), but you might also want to check your folder path.

In future you should report any exceptions or logcat entries you see and more detail in general about HOW the operation fails. Also try other things such as creating folders in your private data space using *Environment. getDataDirectory()*

Comment: it did not fail it just saves in the gallery instead of a new created folder in my sd card.

Comment: @user3042516 There is no gallery folder as such, rather the gallery shows media files Android has found when it scans various folders on the device. This means your file must be somewhere, just not in the place you are expecting. Also note that Android has abused the term "SD card" to mean secondary internal storage (typically /mnt/sdcard from ADB) and not a removable SD card (typically /mnt/sdcard2).

Comment: Thanks for telling me! However, since it is stored into a secondary sdcard, how do i path the gridview to the folder where the images are supposedly stored in? Thanks in advance=)

Comment: If you have to cache the bitmap to the disk (which I don't necessarily recommend by the way), you should use internal storage anyway: Environment.getDataDirectory(). Anything written to any type of external storage is readable by most apps, which is insecure.

Comment: so do i change all of the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to Environment.getDataDirectory()?

Comment: This conversation is wandering off-topic somewhat. You need to break your problem up into lots of little problems (can I write anything to the drive? can I send an existing picture to another app? etc...) and try and solve each one. Any that you can't solve with sweat + Google, post as new questions to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the permission to AndroidManifest.xml for STORAGE permissions.
Go to AndroidManifest.xml-> permission tab -> click add -> uses permission
Name:android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE if necessary.

Comment: yup. i have already done that in my manifest.but it still doesnt create a folder when the folder doesnt exist.D= thanks anyways