# Creating and writing a file android

Tags: android, io, internal-storage

Im trying to write to a file in my android app.

I dont think its creating the file though.

1. is the code to correct?
2. if it is, how do I locate the file on my phone? Is it hidden?

The code resides in an Activity fragment

```
        String FILENAME = "alarmStatus";
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write("Hello".getBytes());
            fos.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Have you stepped through the code?  What does the documentation say?  Asking a question here should be your fifth or sixth step, not your second (after writing and executing the code.)

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for your reply. At first I was getting "Read only File System" errors when I tried to introduce a directory to write the file to. Ive read thedeveloper docs and this I tried to follow their example. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: 08-14 00:01:20.847: W/System.err(21797): java.io.IOException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: Trouble is I dont know if the file where the file is, I use a file manager app to try and find it but I cant see it. I also dont know how to change the file permissions upon creation.

Comment: You won't be able to find the file using a file manager app as `openFileOutput(...)` creates a file in internal storage which is restricted to your app. I can't think of a valid reason why you're getting an error indicating the file system is read-only though. That method call doesn't require any special permissions.

Comment: Did you try just openFileOutput() instead of getActivity().openFileOutput()?

Comment: @MobileDeveloper : The `Fragment` class doesn't have an `openFileOutput` method. That method is only available to classes which extend `ContextWrapper` or `Context`.

Comment: Your app needs file writing permissions to write a file.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121833/permission-to-write-to-the-sd-card

Comment: I have already added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" /> to the manifest, doesnt work Im afraid

Comment: @Squonk, thanks for your comment, do you know the write way to write and read to a file in a fragment please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Ive found a solution, abit long winded but it does work, please poke at it :)

```
      File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir() +"alarmStatus.txt");
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            out.write("Hello".getBytes());
           out.close();

        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        BufferedReader in =null;

        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            System.out.println("File Output is "+in.readLine());


        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```