# Access removable SD card

Tags: kivy, pyjnius

I'm using this code to access `SD card`:

```
import os
from os.path import join
from jnius import autoclass
#from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

#request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
#                     Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
Environment = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
self.working_directory = os.path.join(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "my_app_dir")
if not os.path.exists(self.working_directory):
  os.makedirs(self.working_directory)
```

Howerver I noticed that the data is created only on internal SD card. How can I access removable phone SD card and which permissions do I need (I need to read and write there)? My data is quite large, so I need it to save on removable SD card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, "external storage" is not the same as "removable storage". The external storage is basically [defined by Google originally](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#filesExternal) as "a storage which isn't always accessible", e.g. because it is mounted to a PC via USB. It's safe to say that since Android 4 this concept has [lost most of the meaning](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Which kind of storage is actually used by the system as "external" is [completely up](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) to the device manufacturer. You should not assume that it's the removable media. Neither should you assume the removable media has more available storage space, or even *exists on the system*.

If there *is* one, though, then the correct way to handle it in your case [is to use](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) `Context.getExternalFilesDirs()`. This method would then return multiple paths over which you would need to iterate, checking `File.getFreeSpace()` to figure out which directory has got more available storage space.

(Hint: on a typical phone with a removable SD card the second item in the list returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()` is [*probably*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981975/2193305) the removable media but that's a dirty hack.)

A modern approach would be to study the Storage Access Framework, here's [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider).

Comment: Are there some examples, how to use SAF in python (kivy)? I don't know `Java` or `Kotlin`